# Generating random numbers in C++ using std::random_device

Tags: c++, random

I generate random numbers in C++ using the following piece of code

```
std::random_device rdev {};
std::default_random_engine generator {rdev()};
std::uniform_int_distribution dist {a, b};
```

Similarly

```
std::default_random_engine generator {std::random_device{}()};
std::uniform_int_distribution dist {a, b};
```

What i'm trying to understand is the mechanics behind generating an engine using a seed value. random_device obtains a seed using various information from your operating system. This value is used to initialize an engine object. For the first snippet of code presented here, if `rdev` is an object, why do we pass in that value in to the engine as `rdev()`. Why are we using function notation on an object of a class ?

For the second snippet of code, how are we able to generate a `std::random_device` object by just using the class name?

I'm not sure if my issue in understanding this is specific to random number generation or something bigger involving the C++ language itself.

Comment: *"For the second snippet of code, how are we able to generate a std::random_device object by just using the class name?"* - because you're *not* just using the class name. That trailing set of `{}` is there for a reason.

Comment: It's more about the C++ language. Objects you can apply the `()` operator to are called [functors](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html), and most of your other queries can be answered by looking at some ways of instantiating objects.

Comment: "Why are we using function notation on an object of a class ? " It's an operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::random_device` overloads the parenthesis operator to give it function-like syntax. It more-or-less looks like this:

```
class random_device {
    /*...*/
public:
    uint32_t operator()() {
        return /*...*/;
    }
};
```

It can then be invoked on an object

```
std::random_device device;
uint32_t value = device();
```

or on a temporary (which is still technically an object)

```
uint32_t value = std::random_device{}();
uint32_t value_2 = std::random_device()(); //Equivalent syntax
```

The `operator()` overload can also be overloaded in other ways.

```
struct multiplies_by_3 {
    uint32_t operator()(uint32_t value) const {
        return value * 3;
    }
};

multiplies_by_3 multiplier;
uint32_t value = multiplier(15); //45
uint32_t value_2 = multiplies_by_3{}(20); //60
uint32_t value_3 = multiplies_by_3()(25); //75

struct subtracts_first_from_second {
    uint32_t operator()(uint32_t first, uint32_t second) const {
        return second - first;
    }
};

subtracts_first_from_second subtractor;
uint32_t value = subtractor(15, 17); //2
uint32_t value_2 = subtracts_first_from_second{}(20, 29); //9
uint32_t value_3 = subtracts_first_from_second()(25, 17); //Underflows to some large number
```

Answer (score 6):

The `std::random_device` object itself is not used as the seed.  A `random_device` is a true-random-number generator.  Calling its parentheses operator yields a sample from it.  Unfortunately, generating true random numbers tends to be more expensive than generating pseudorandom numbers, so as a compromise one tends to generate a single truly random number to pass as a seed to a pseudorandom generator.  So in your first example, the `random_device` is being sampled a single time by calling its parentheses operator (`rdev()`), returning a truly random value which is used as the seed for the `std::default_random_engine` object.

The second example does precisely the same thing, except that in this case the `random_device` is a temporary.  In C++ you can construct a temporary by directly calling a class's constructor, in this case using brace initialization.  In other words, the expression `std::random_device{}` returns a temporary, default-constructed `random_device` object, whose parentheses operator is then invoked as in the previous example to yield a seed.